# Blender not rendering water in F12 render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I created some sort a object and can't render the water flowing over it.

Viewport render:

[image]

Final render:

[image]

It's not render restriction because I've already tried pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and removing it.

Comment: Can you post a .blend or screenshots?

Comment: http://oi59.tinypic.com/jacac8.jpg this is what I have while "capturing with camera"/viewing... And this I get while rendering http://oi60.tinypic.com/r0wp44.jpg

Comment: @Adrian Are there any modifiers on the fluid object? If not, could you upload the .blend?

Comment: http://speedy.sh/GaJwM/cosiekblend.blend here you are.

Comment: @Adrian have you used different versions of blender on the same file? Different computers?

Comment: As I already answered down I have not used other computers or blender versions. It's on the same computer and with the same blender version. It's even done within one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Numberpad /</kbd> Seems to fix the issue, you were in *local view*.

<sub>I have no idea why that would cause an issue, and would definitly upvote an answer detailing why!</sub>

Comment: That's the opposite of what should happen with local view. Viewport render shows only the local view object/s while final render will show them all. Turning local view back on and things work right so my guess is it was saved in one version of blender then opened in another, giving the discrepancy in settings.

Comment: I have discovered blender like 2 days ago... So I have downloaded only one version of blender. Thanks everyone for answers :)

Comment: If this answered your question, please hit the check mark to mark this answer as accepted.